# "Сниться" с предлогами

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, глаголы

Подскажите, с какими предлогами после глагола можно употребить "сниться"? Снилось про, снилось о?

Answer (score 1):

СНИТЬСЯ, снюсь, снишься; нсв. кому. Видеться во сне, являться в сновидениях. Часто снится один и тот же сон. Вы снитесь мне почти каждую ночь. □безл. Мне снилось, что я купаюсь в море. И во сне не снилось что-л. (о чём-л. совершенно непредвиденном).

Но: сон о, про. Обратите внимание: в данном случае предлог "про" имеет разговорный характер.

Answer (score 1):

“Сниться” не употребляется с предлогами.

СЛОВАРЬ СОЧЕТАЕМОСТИ СЛОВ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА под редакцией П. Н. ДЕНИСОВА, В. В. МОРКОВКИНА:

> СНИ'ТЬСЯ, снюсь, снишься, снятся, несов.-, присниться, приснюсь, приснйшься, приснятся, сов.
>   Представляться, казаться во сне, являться в сновидениях.
>   Сниться кому: (о человеке) ~ матери, мне, Анне ... Сниться кому-л. во сне.
>   Сниться когда: — вчера, сегодня, по ночам, ночью ... Сниться (только несов.) как часто: ~ часто, редко, всегда, постоянно, каждую ночь, временами, иногда ...
>   Кто-л. снился кому-л.; что-л. (какой-л. сон ...) снилось кому-л.
>   Кому-л. снилось (безл.), что (будто ...) (с придат.).
>   О Мне часто снятся те ребята, Друзья моих военных дней (Матусовский). Мне снилось, будто мы с вами танцуем вальс (Куприн). Что тебе сегодня приснилось?